Integrating backport-iwlwifi into kernel source
I want to use backported version of iwlwifi (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git/) with Jetson Linux 5.10.104 to fix some bugs that was fixed in newer versions of the driver. Suggested method of the building backported version of the driver is to build it separately from the Linux kernel build (https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release).
Is there any way it "integrate" this backported driver into Linux source and build it during Linux kernel compilation?
